# Choosing between different expression factorizations in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

Say I have an expression as follows:

```
a*b*c + b*c + a*d
```

One could factorize it as:

```
b*(a*c + c) + (a*d)
```

or as

```
c*(a*b + b) + (a*d)
```

or as

```
a*d + b*c*(a + 1)
```

among other possibilities.

For other expressions, the # of possibilities can be much larger.

My question is, does SymPy have any utility that allows the user to choose which of them to display? Is there a way to specify the common factor/s to use when factorizing / grouping terms in an expression?

**EDIT:** As @user772649 points out below, I can use `collect` for this. However, `collect`  seems to give different outputs depending on the initial factorization of the mathematical expression e.g.:

```
a,b,c,d = symbols("a,b,c,d")

# These two equations are mathematically equivalent:
eq1 = a*b*c + b*c + a*d
eq2 = a*d + b*c*(a + 1)

print collect(eq1, a)
print collect(eq2, a)
```

prints:

```
a*(b*c + d) + b*c
a*d + b*c*(a + 1)
```

The equations `eq1` and `eq2` are mathematically equivalent, but `collect` outputs a different factorization for each of them, despite of the fact that the call to the `collect` command was the same for both. This brings me to the following two questions:

1. Is there a way to "expand" an expression before calling `collect`?
2. Is there a way of "collecting" (factoring an expression) in a way that is invariant to the initial factorization without having to expand the expression first?

Comment: Can't you factor it to `c * b * (a + 1) + (a * d)`?

Comment: Yes, thanks @TorelTwiddler. I added it to the question.

Comment: @Don Roby: ?? I am working with very large expressions and would like to get a factorization with respect to a specific set of monomials.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted.  I've deleted my dumb comment.  Nothing to do with operator precedence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use collect():

```
from sympy import *

a,b,c,d = symbols("a,b,c,d")
eq = a * b * c + b * c + a * d
print collect(eq, b)
print collect(eq, c)
print collect(eq, b*c)
```

the output is:

```
a*d + b*(c + a*c)
a*d + c*(b + a*b)
a*d + b*c*(1 + a)
```

Comment: Thanks @user772649. Is there a way to "extract" the symbols from an expression before calling `collect`? I'm having problems working with expressions that were built within functions or expressions that use symbols that I don't have access to anymore. For example, if I call `collect(expression, Symbol('Variable'))` where expression has several instances of `Variable`, it does not work.

Comment: can you give an example? as the example in the question, collect(eq, Symbol("b")*Symbol("c")) works.

Comment: Yes @user772649. I have updated the question, I think the problem is that `collect` outputs a different result for different (mathematically equivalent) expressions.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might be nice is if `collect` would collect on previously grouped sub-expressions if more than one symbol is given. But either giving a product to collect on (as @HYRY showed) or something like the following is possible:

```
def separatevars_additively(expr, symbols=[]):
    from sympy import factor_terms
    free = set(symbols) or expr.free_symbols
    d = {}
    while free:
        f = free.pop()
        expr, dep = expr.as_independent(f, as_Add=True)
        if dep.has(*free):
            return None
        d[f] = factor_terms(dep)
    if expr:
        d[0] = expr
    return d

var('a:d')
eq = a*b*c + b*c + a*d
def do(i):
    return sum(separatevars_additively(eq,[i]).values())
for i in eq.free_symbols:
    print('%s: %s' % (i, do(i)))
```

gives

```
b: a*d + b*c*(a + 1)
a: a*(b*c + d) + b*c
c: a*d + b*c*(a + 1)
d: a*b*c + a*d + b*c
```